# How to create a snackbar/toast alert when connected and disconnected and have the message show the type of connection?

Tags: flutter, dart, connection

I have a task that I have to create, like a snack bar message in Flutter. If the device is connected, the Snackbar or Toast package will show the message + green background, and when disconnected, it will show the message + red background color.
The message will show by what we are connected (by cellular, wifi, or etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Start by adding the **connectivity_plus** package, it includes a simple listener which you can implement in your app to be notified if the connectivity changed (disconnected, wifi, cellular..)

> https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

**onConnectivityChanged.listen** will return a **ConnectivityResult** which you can use to show different types of snackbars, here is an example :

> https://pub.dev/packages/top_snackbar_flutter

Hope it works for you, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for a package that constantly checks the Internet connectivity.

Use package: https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker

It checks for an internet (data) connection by opening a socket to a list of addresses.

This package can reliably determine if the device has a connection to the global network, e.i. has access to the Internet.